# Como ler string a partir de uma palavra especifica?

Tags: php, string, caracteres

minha dúvida  é o seguinte:

Se eu tenho a frase "O rato roeu a roupa do rei de roma"

Como eu faço para ler somente de "Roeu" até "roma"?

Isso sem usar numeros, porque serão varias frases de tamanhos diferentes.

Procurei na documentação do php as funções strings encontrei varias mas não consegui fazer exatamente essa.

Para um exemplo ainda mais pratico, o que eu tenho na realidade uma lista de links mas eles estão como

/79811/out.php=www.youtube.com=?video1
/798354664561/out.php=www.youtube.com=?video1

Essas strings tem larguras diferentes e eu queroa pegar do www até o fim da string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal assim?

```
$a = '79811/out.php=www.youtube.com=?video1';
$b = 'www';
echo substr( $a, strpos($a, $b);
```

Comment: Daria certo de fosse apenas uma frase nas na realidade eu tenho uma lista grande de frases.

Comment: Você perguntou como ler uma string a partir de uma posição. O resto da lógica: colocar a string na variável $a a partir de um um objeto qualquer e atribuir os resultados a outro objeto seria com você.

Answer (score 0):

exibir de "3" até "8"

```
$frase = "123456789";


$primeira = strripos("$frase", '3');
$utima    = strripos("$frase", '8');

    $retirar = $utima - $primeira ;
    $exibir = substr($frase, $primeira, $retirar);

    echo "$exibir" ;


 exibir : 34567
```